# Is there a way to resample dataframe and apply customised function but with different frequence?

Tags: python, pandas

I've defined a customised function using an array as argument.
I've a DataFrame where the indexes are minutely timestamps. They look like:

```
2022-05-12 00:01:03 
2022-05-12 00:03:17
2022-05-12 00:06:10
```

What I want to do is resampling the data so I have a dataframe where the indexes are:

```
2022-05-12 00:02:00
2022-05-12 00:03:00
2022-05-12 00:04:00
2022-05-12 00:05:00
2022-05-12 00:06:00
2022-05-12 00:07:00
```

I know I could use

```
df.resample('1min', label='right', closed='right').apply(lambda x: custom_f(x))
```

The problem is my customised function would be applied on the last minute and I want it to be applied on the last 10 minutes for example. So the result at the row

```
2022-05-12 00:07:00
```

would be computed on all the rows from the timestamp

```
2022-05-11 23:57:00
```

What is the best way to do that ? I can do a for loop with 10 iterations and change the origin of the resample each time but creating and concatenating all the dataframes would be a mess. Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function. Since this function also accepts a time period as the moving window size, you could set the window parameter to the desired `10min` span.

```py
def custom_f(x):
    return sum(x*2)

df = df.resample('1min', label='right', closed='right').interpolate()
df = df.rolling('10min').apply(lambda x: custom_f(x))
```

Comment: Doesn't work because It's gonna use data from the resampling df. So basically, it's gonna apply custom_f on 10 rows and I'd like it to be applied on all the rows over the past 10 minutes (not only these after resampling).